# What is the kebab case for a forward slash to use with Vue?

Tags: vue.js, key, mozilla, vuejs3

Keycodes are deprecated and we can no longer use `@keyup.keyCode.191`

I tried using

- `@keyup.slash`
- `@keyup.divide`
- All possible values from [KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this directly. From stepping through the code it seems to be comparing the modifier to the `event.key`, which would be `'/'` in this case. You can't write `@keyup./` as that isn't considered valid.

You could achieve the same effect by performing the `key` test yourself:

```js
Vue.createApp({
  methods: {
    onSlash (ev) {
      if (ev.key !== '/') {
        return
      }
      
      console.log('/ pressed')
    }
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.2/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input @keyup="onSlash">
</div>
```

Comment: Correct this is inline with the documentation: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/keycode-modifiers.html#migration-strategy

Comment: @danger89 I added that section to the documentation after writing this answer, so it isn't quite the independent source it might appear to be.